# Updating a collection on Mongo

Tags: mongodb

Let´s say I have the following

> db.companies.insertOne({name: "Fresh Apples Inc", isStartup: true, employees: 33, funding: 12345678901234567890, details:{ceo: "Mark"}, tags: [{title: "super"}, {title: "perfect"}], foundingDate: new Date(), insertedAt: new Timestamp()})

Now I need to update this and include a new detail so I would have details: `{ceo: "Mark", city: "New York"}`

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c71b362b3458dab6ca76419"),
        "name" : "Fresh Apples Inc",
        "isStartup" : true,
        "employees" : 33,
        "funding" : 12345678901234567000,
        **"details" : {
            "ceo" : "Mark",
            "address" : "New York"
        },**
        "tags" : [
                {
                        "title" : "super"
                },
                {
                        "title" : "perfect"
                }
        ],
        "foundingDate" : ISODate("2019-02-23T20:56:02.380Z"),
        "insertedAt" : Timestamp(1550955362, 1)
}
```

How can I update this without losing **"ceo" : "Mark"**?

Comment: I think this example from official documentation may be helpful: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
db.companies.update({"_id" : ObjectId("5c71b362b3458dab6ca76419")},{$set: {"details.city": "New York"}})
```

Comment: Thanks you! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use an update operation ([`db.collection.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db-collection-update), [`db.collection.findOneAndUpdate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#db-collection-findoneandupdate) or equivalent) with [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set) operator.

If you want to [update a field in an embedded document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents) your `update` parameter in the update function should look like this:

```
{ $set: { "embededDocument.someField": "some value" } }
```

In this specific case you could use the following command:

```
db.companies.update({ name: "Fresh Apples Inc" }, { $set: { "details.address": "New York" } })
```

*Note that you should rather use `ObjectId` as there may be multiple documents with the same name, but I think this is clearer to read.*